# Expand only some of the categorized columns in a viewPanel upon opening

Tags: xpages

I am using a ViewPanel to show a categorized view. This view has 4 columns of categories. There are 3 additional columns that are totaled.

I want to open this view so that the first 3 categorized columns are expended and the 4th one is collapsed.

Is there some type of SSJS / CSJS that I can add to the view that can do this?

I didn't see an option to expand/collapse a column upon opening the view in the Properties of the viewPanel.

I tried using the collapse option on the back-end view but that has no effect on the Xpage side. I tried hide detail rows, but they show up anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, just change the expand level of your datasource:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="NameOfYourView" expandLevel="4" />
</xp:this.data>
```

**EDIT:**

You can even control this by adding a simple URL parameter: *nameOfXPage.xsp?expandLevel=3*

Have a nice day

Sven