# Is it possible to have multiple expand/collapse rows in the viewPanel?

Tags: xpages

I am sorry this post is quite long.

I have read this question "[Expand only some of the categorized columns in a viewPanel upon opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524850/expand-only-some-of-the-categorized-columns-in-a-viewpanel-upon-opening)" and try to apply the solution to my case, but it does not work (I think maybe it is different case or I use it incorrectly). Therefore I would to seek your advice/suggestion on my question.

I have one form, one view, one xpage and one custom control.
I paste the custom control to the xpage for testing the result.

In the custom control, I put a view from Container Controls to display the data stored in the view.

I would like to show the source code of the custom control here to let you know what I am planning to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="TestView">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ItemNumber" id="viewColumn1">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Item Number" id="viewColumnHeader1">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ItemDescription" id="viewColumn2">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Item Description"
            id="viewColumnHeader2">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="PreviousItems" id="viewColumn3">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Previous Items"
            id="viewColumnHeader3">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
 </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

I can imagine the viewPanel will look like a table with 3 columns which are Item Number, Item Description and Previous Items.

I would like to ask is it possible to have multiple expand/collapse rows in the viewPanel?

Currently, I am not able to post a picture to show my imagination of the table here, therefore I would like to describe it row by row.

A. For the first row, it will look like as normal row, I mean it will have Item Number, Item Description and Previous Items to show

B. For the second row, I would like to specify the First category. That row will be able to expand or collapse.

C. If I expand the First category (that is in the third row), there will be a sub-category (it belongs to the First category).  That row will be able to expand or collapse. Item Number and Item Description only will display in the third row because it is a sub-category (in order not to get confuse, I may say this sub-category is sub-category1), so it will not have Previous Items.

D.If I expand the sub-category1 (the fourth row), the item will display in Item Description and it will have Previous Items. It is because it is an actual item that belongs to the First category and the sub-category1.

E. The fifth row will show the item similar to the fourth row.

F. In the sixth row. there will be another sub-category (in order not to get confuse, I may say this sub-category is sub-category2). This sub-category2 will show Item Number and Item Description and no Previous Items.

G. If expand the sixth row, that is in the seventh row, it will display in Item Description and it will have Previous Items. It is because it is an actual item that belongs to the First category and the sub-category2.

H. In the eighth row, I would like to specify the Second category. That row will be able to expand or collapse.

I. If expand the eighth row, there will a sub-category in the ninth row. (it belongs to the Second category and I may call this sub-category is sub-category3 )

J. If expand the ninth row, there will be an actual item show in tenth row and that item belongs to the Second category and the sub-category3.

K. In the tenth row, there will be another sub-category (sub-category4), it is belong to the Second category. It will be able to expand or collapse.

L. In the next row there will be an actual item that belongs to the Second category and the sub-category4.

That's all for my description of the result that the table will look like.

According to my description above, there will be 6 places to expand/collapse which are the First category, Second category, sub-category1, sub-category2, sub-category3 and sub-category4.

If it is possible to have multiple expand/collapse rows in the viewPanel, how to do it ?

It is because I input data in the form and show in xpage, the result is the table (viewPanel) shows the data by each row and cannot expand/collapse.

I should be grateful if you would give advice or suggestion on this issue.

I apologize that my post is quite long.

Thank you very much.

Yours sincerely,

beginner

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20ViewGrid

Comment: Hello @Frantisek Kossuth, thank you for your comment.<br/> I downloaded the zip file from the website and try to run it. However
I got an Error 500, it said HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception.<br/>I guess the version of the zip file is for IBM 
Lotus Domino Designer 8.5.3 or later version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xpages+500

Comment: Hello Frantisek Kossuth, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try putting the categories in the Lotus Notes view. The component PanelView  transforms the Notes View categories to expand/collapse sections in web.

Comment: Hello @Txemanu, thank you for your answer, I tried to categories include sub-categories in view and then I open the browser to see result. The data still show by each row and cannot expand/collapse.<br/> More information about the view, currently there are 5 columns (Item Number, Item Categories, Item Sub-Categories, Item-Description and Previous Item). <br/> I delete the view and re-create view, the data cannot expand/collapse. <br/> I am sorry to ask where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi. I would try building a simple view with one categorie, and then creating the XPage + PanelView. If this works, add more categories and see what happens. Good luck!